# User can't find npm from within a bash script

Tags: bash, npm

Context: I am writing a set of scripts to deploy a Meteor app to a proprietary server running Ubuntu 16.04. For this, I have created a user named `meteor` which owns the process that runs the app.

When I run the individual lines of code manually, they work fine, but from inside a bash script, the `meteor` user is unable to find `npm`.

Here is the proof that the `meteor` user has access to npm:

```
$ sudo -u meteor -H bash -l
$ which npm
/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin/npm
```

I have two scripts. The first is run as root, using `sudo`, and this sets the user to `meteor` before running the second script.

Here is the contents of the script run as root:

```
sudo -u meteor -H bash -l << HERE
./test.sh
HERE
```

Here is the contents of `test.sh`:

```
echo -n "whoami: "; whoami
which npm
echo "<<< which npm"
```

And here is the output:

```
whoami: meteor
<<< which npm
```

As you can see, from inside the bash script, the `meteor` user has no access to `npm`. What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a PATH issue. Add `echo PATH=$PATH` to test.sh and run again, do you see `/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin` in it?

Comment: @oguzismail You are right: I see `/home/meteor/bin` and `/home/meteor/.local/bin` but no path that includes `.nvm`. How can I tell the `test.sh` file to use the PATH that is usually available to the `meteor` user?

Comment: Well I don't know, you can add it to meteor's .bashrc manually (like `PATH=/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin:$PATH`). Many similar questions have been asked before, now that you know the problem I think you can solve it on your own